# How to sort an array of objects by a key and then push the other key to a new array in the sorted order?

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have an array of objects called `result`:

```
{ "name": "C:\\file.json", "relevance": 0.5 }

{ "name": "C:\\folder", "relevance": 0.5454545454545454 }

{ "name": "C:\\file_1.txt", "relevance": 0.1 }
```

How do we sort it by `relevance` key and push the `name` values into a new array in the sorted order, so that we get the following `arr`:

```
["C:\\folder", "C:\\file.json", "C:\\file_1.txt"]
```

### UPDATE

It's **not** a duplicate! I don't know why people in `js` threads always marking answers as duplicate, even when they very much aren't

Comment: what is actually the specific problem by using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and later with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm not sure how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this;

```js
var result = [ { "name": "C:\\file.json", "relevance": 0.5 }, { "name": "C:\\folder", "relevance": 0.5454545454545454 }, { "name": "C:\\file_1.txt", "relevance": 0.1 } ]
var newArray = result.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b.relevance) - parseFloat(a.relevance)).map(item => item.name);
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: hmm, It puts `name` item with the relevance `0.5454545454545454` after the `name` item with relevance `0.5` even though the latter one is smaller. How can I apply `toFixed(1)` in the process and only sort them after that?

Comment: @Un1 Don't use `.toFixed`, which produces a string. Instead, compare `Math.round(a.relevance * 10)`

Comment: I updated the answer. Would you try it again ?

Comment: @lucky I just did, it seems like it puts them into the array in random order. It puts `0.7` after `0.6666666666666666` even thought it's bigger, I don't know why

Comment: Would you try it again ?

Comment: @lucky thank you very much kind sir, that works!